# Show certain object from the array as first item in flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have the following array of objects (just example, actual cases could be a lot more)

```
const items = [{/* for user 1 */}, {/* for user 2 */}, ... {/* for user 10 */}];
```

Im displaying the array as list in `Flatlist`

```
<FlatList
   data={items}
   renderItem={renderItem}
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}
   initialNumToRender={20}
/>
```

Where renderItem is like this

```
const renderItem = ({ item: user }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity 
    activeOpacity={1} 
    style={styles.items}
    onPress={() => {clickMe(user)}}
    >
        <UserAvatar url={user.url} />
        <Text style={styles.userName}>{ user.name }</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

All is working well and fine so far, and the list can display properly.

But say if i want to display user 9 as the first item on the list, how would i do that?

i tried doing it like this

```
const ninthUser = items.find( i => i.id === 9 );
const listWithoutNinth = items.filter( i => i.id !== 9 );
const listWithNinthAsFirstItem = [ ninthUser, ...listWithoutNinth ];
```

And pass `listWithNinthAsFirstItem` to the data prop of the Flatlist but somehow it wouldn't work.

Comment: Any Error or what's the output you got passing listWithNinthAsFirstItem ?

Comment: No error, it displays normally but not with user 9 as first item on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should involve state.

```html
const [ sortedItems, setSortedItems ] =  useState([])
const startSort = () => {
  const ninthUser = items.find( i => i.id === 9 );
  const listWithoutNinth = items.filter( i => i.id !== 9 );
  const listWithNinthAsFirstItem = [ ninthUser, ...listWithoutNinth ];
setSortedItems(listWithNinthAsFirstItem)
}
useEffect(() => {
  if (items) {
    startSort()
  }  
}, [items])
```

and then in FlatList pass data as sortedItems

> <FlatList    data={sortedItems}    renderItem={renderItem}
> keyExtractor={item => item.id}    initialNumToRender={20} />